# How can I achieve this modal design with react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying design like below image with react native.If anyone have worked like this modal design over the toolbar then please help me.

[image: Design Sample](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg)[![enter image description here]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v97rH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a Modal with a embedded TouchableOpacity combined with some styling for positioning.

Please refer this 
https://snack.expo.io/SJrDAC8Qr

```
 render() {
    return (
      <>
      <View>
        <Appbar.Header>
          <Appbar.Content title="Title" subtitle="Subtitle" />
          <Appbar.Action icon="search" onPress={() => this.setState({displayModal: true})} />
        </Appbar.Header>
        <View>
          <Text>Main content!</Text>
        </View>

      </View>
{/*Modal code*/}
       <Modal transparent={true} visible={this.state.displayModal}>
{/*Container .. clicking this closes the modal*/}
          <TouchableOpacity style={{flex:1}} onPress={() => this.setState({displayModal:false})}>
            <View style={{backgroundColor:'blue', position:'absolute', right:0, width:200, height: 200}}>
              <Text style={{color:'#ffffff'}}>Hello World!</Text>

            </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </Modal>
      </>
    );
  }
```

Not very nicely styled but I guess it does what you want